# Permissions dialogue not showing on fragment in api 23

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am amateur in android,I am trying to upload files to server from app,I need to request permission from user but the dialogue doesn't pop up in fragment.
I have a *FilePath* class which helps get path,The verify permissions method is also in this class which should bring up permissions dialogue

```
public class FilePath{
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

    };


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {




        // check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                            + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                        Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                        selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }


    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                       String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = { column };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }


    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }


    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri
                .getAuthority());
    }

    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);


        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            Log.d("Permission Checked","Checked permision!!!!!");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

            );
        }

    }

}
```

I then call this verify permissions method in the fragment class onCreate

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, container, false);
ivAttachment = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);
bUpload = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
tvFileName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);
bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

FilePath.verifyStoragePermissions(this.getActivity());


return v;
}
```

The fragment is contained in a `BottomBar` which is added on **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 10;

    BottomBar mBottomBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this,savedInstanceState);

        mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main,new OnMenuTabClickListener()

        {


            public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int i) {
                if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemone)
                {   NewsFRagment f = new NewsFRagment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();

                }
                else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemtwo)
                {
                    Cardsfragment f =new Cardsfragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();
                }
                else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemthree)
                {
                    PhoneFragment f =new PhoneFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();
                }
                else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemfour)
                {
                    UploadFragment f =new UploadFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();

                }
                else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemfive)
                {
                    FavoritesFragment f =new FavoritesFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container,f).commit();
                }
            }



            @Override
            public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int i) {

            }
        });
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#F44336");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1,"#9C27B0");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2,"#03A9F4");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(3,"#795548");
        mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(4,"#FF6F00");

        BottomBarBadge unread;
        unread = mBottomBar.makeBadgeForTabAt(3,"#FF0000",13);
        unread.show();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I tested this without the Bottom Bar and permission dialogue pops up but I don't know why it doesn't on `BottomBar` Fragment I have tried to rectify but I am unable to... please help!

Comment: Here is the example and code to ask permission which is also explain handle `never ask check` and `deny` https://androidexampleblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/androids-runtime-permission-example/

Comment: when i try to use code Permission is denied before dialogue pops up to ask for permission

Comment: Have u mention required permissions in your Manifest ??

Comment: Wow,youre right,I didnt add it correctly till just now Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission dialog is not shown if user denies a permission. In the second launch, user will get a "Never ask again" option to prevent application from asking this permission in the future.

However it is quite bad in term of UX if user does something but there is nothing to interact back. This case has to be handled as well. Before calling requestPermissions, you need to check to show a rationale dialog about why application needs the being-requested permission through Activity's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale

The result are rational dialog will be shown when this permission is requested for the first time and also be shown if user has ever marked that permission as Never ask again. For the latter case, onRequestPermissionsResult will be called with PERMISSION_DENIED without any permission grant dialog.

I have written a small [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/passiondroid/cd2ad32e7ba26f4e47ae) to ask for runtime permissions.

Also check this [blog](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) for complete understanding of runtime permissions.

Comment: the thing is permission is not granted as dialogue does not pop up at all,so there is no option for user to accept or deny it,it simply doesent pop up even in first launch

Comment: I got new code to implement in my project which handles all errors,The problem right now is permission is denied before dialogue requesting permission pops, there is no option to allow or deny but onRequestPermissionsResult is getting called,what could cause this